# given x, compute minimum k for which x * 10^k is integer

Tags: python, floating-point

I have small (Python) command line tool to which the user provides a float, e.g.,

```
foobar 3.141
```

and I'd like to compute the granularity of the number, i.e., find the minimum `k` for which `x * 10^k` is an integer (up to a given tolerance). Note that the number may be represented in different ways (`3141.0e-3` etc.), so counting the number of characters after `.` isn't necessarily going to cut it.

This

```
def get_granularity(x):
    for k in range(100):
        if abs(x - int(x)) < 1.0e-15 * x:
            break
    x *= 10
    return k
```

works, but I don't like it too much since it makes an assumption about the maximum `k` (`99` in this case). One could invite `log10` to the party, but perhaps there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: You count the number of digits after the decimal dot.

Comment: You're about to run into the fun world of representing floating point values :) For example `0.1+0.2 == 0.30000000000000004`, so I'd bet you'd *think* that `get_granularity(0.1+0.2) == 1`, but nope

Comment: For `x` of a binary floating point type, your question is essentially meaningless, unless `x` *happens to be* exactly representable. If the number is available as a decimal string, the answer is trivial.

Comment: You can't use floating point for this.  If you do, you will be subject to roundoff errors which will sometimes produce the wrong result.  Keep it as a string, ignore trailing zeroes, and count the digits to the right of the decimal point.

Comment: @CoryKramer Thanks for the comment. I'm aware of the floating point mess, that's why the example code contains a tolerance. Won't work every time, but I yet have to come up with an example that gets it completely wrong.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem A practical suggestion, thank you. Unfortunately, the number may have different representations, so I'd have to parse the string as a floating point number though.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thanks for the comment. Round-off errors could be treated by a tolerance as in the example code. Do you see a problem there?

Comment: @NicoSchlömer: the problem I think is that the least significant part of floating point is terribly chaotic: adding two numbers with very few digits, can generate an error with a lot of digits, and vice versa. So I think this problem is terribly conditioned.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Would you say that adding a tolerance as in the example code may alleviate the problem?

Comment: Floating point "tolerance" will only help if you decide to restrict the precision to less than what a native floating point number can hold, rounding to the nearest decimal fraction.  If you use strings, on the other hand, you can support arbitrary precision, e.g. thousands of fractional digits, with no possibility of error.

Comment: Just a note about your assumption: above `1/eps()` all floating-point numbers are integers (`x = int(x)` exactly), so the most times you can execute `x *= 10` is `ceil(log10(1/eps()) - log10(realmin())) = 324`. Also, I suspect your function produces an unexpected result for `x=eps()`.

Comment: Also, have you considered the mathematical aspect of this? There are numbers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation) that don't have nice rational approximations, and there is also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem. For example, what is the right output for `sqrt(2)`? (If you do it in bigfloats, `10^k*sqrt(2)` is not within `1e-3` of an integer for `k<60`.)